# Where to put my Classes/Objects - General Project Design

Tags: class, object

Lately I seem to be struggling to organize all of the different Classes/Objects I am working with.  In my case, I work for a company that has 3 core products that are different - but share some core functionality.  So, they will also share classes.  To muddy the waters some more, I am writing ASP.NET MVC app - which has an implicit location for Classes (the Model folder).

So - here is how we are currently doing things.  I am going to refer to the product as `NewProduct`.  `xxx` is the company name:

- `xxx.Core` - Classes used in all products.  These could be helper functions, actual classes with logic, etc.
- `xxx.NewProduct.Web` - The MVC Web App for the NewProduct.  The Models folder is empty.
- `xxx.NewProduct.WindowsService` - A Windows service - part of the NewProduct.
- `xxx.NewProduct.Models` - Basically, this replaces the Models folder in the MVC Web app.  They are in their own project so that the **DomainLogic** can fill them and pass them back to the MVC App.
- `xxx.NewProduct.Objects` - Classes with logic (not just Skeletons like **Models**) that are shared between **Web** and **WindowsService**.
- `xxx.NewProduct.DataAccess` - This is the DAL, not all that important to my question here.
- `xxx.NewProduct.DomainLogic` - This is the business logic layer (makes calls into DAL).
  Also, if we are to write some other app in the future (Mobile, Desktop, etc) these can be reused by it as well.

My main problem is when I am trying to decide where to put an object, there are times where I am not sure where to put it.  Is this normal?  Do others have this problem?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course it's normal! there is no one right way to divide your modules. but don't spend too much time on this. we are living in IDEs age - you can always refactor. for me, the most important is readability. when other programmers from your team look for the some class/functionality they should not be surprised - that's all. for example i have no idea what can i find in module named Objects (but i don't know .net nor specific of your application).